# Overriding Django Admin get_queryset with raw() results in DatabaseError

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

To speed up my admin page, I've decided to override my `get_queryset()` with a raw query however it results in:

`Database error: Something’s wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make sure the database is readable by the appropriate user.`

Is there some step I'm missing?. I've already confirmed that the query works in PSQL so I don't see what's going wrong. I've tried cutting it down to just the following but it still errors out.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return MyObject.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_myobject')
```

Comment: Can you show the exact table name in your DB?

Comment: Hi Charnel! It's `clients_orderticket`.

Comment: The problem is actually saying what exact happened - your table name is `clients_orderticket` where you're trying to fetch records from `myapp_myobject`.

Comment: Nono, I only used `MyObject` and `myapp_myobject` to explain the problem but my actual query uses the correct names

Comment: Ok, is that possible actuall table name have mixed-case lettering?

Comment: As I mentioned previously, the query is correct. I can run it perfectly fine through PgAdmin and running `print(queryset[0])` is okay but returning it through `get_queryset()` is not

Comment: Ah sorry, now I realized what's wrong - I'll post this in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `raw` return not a [QuerySet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3a807a6f597a97b0fa514039a8ea41fb90769981/django/db/models/query.py#L184) instance but a [RawQuerySet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3a807a6f597a97b0fa514039a8ea41fb90769981/django/db/models/query.py#L1388) that do have iterator protocol and representation implemented but doesn't have a bunch of other methods used by Django views under the hood.

I advice to use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) instead or simply select ID column only from your raw query and then hit another one like `MyObject.objects.filter(id__in=your_ids_list_from_raw)`