# Django SQL get_queryset() in Admin Model does not support RawQueryset

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm

This query should return the total sum of `(quantity - qty_fulfilled)` grouped by `product_id`.

I'm stuck trying to convert this postgres sql query into an ORM query, to be returned in `get_queryset()` in the Admin model. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12354293/5395848).

This sql query works, but `get_queryset()` method in the Admin models does not support `RawQueryset` as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60827362/5395848), so this needs to be in a Queryset form.

```sql
select t1.id, t3.req_from_orders from inventory_inventory t1
left join
product_app_product t2 
on t1.product_id = t2.id
left join
(
    select product_id, sum(quantity) - sum(qty_fulfilled) as req_from_orders
    from order_app_cartitem oac
    group by oac.product_id 
) t3
on t1.product_id = t3.product_id
```

Models:

```
* Inventory
  * product_id (OneToOneField)
  * id (UUID)
* Product
  * id (UUID)
* CartItem
  * id (UUID)
  * product_id (ForeignKey)
  * quantity (int)
  * qty_fulfilled (int)
* Inventory <-> Product <-* CartItem 

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name="Quantity Ordered", default=0)
    qty_fulfilled = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Quantity Fulfilled", validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    
class Inventory(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Tried using `annotate(RawSQL="<query>", params=(param,))` but params cannot take in dynamic ids.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Is there any way to represent this sql query as an ORM query? Added models to make testing easier.